# execute <br> command with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am writing text from the `textarea` into the database and want to show it in the frontend (slider) with the html - `<br>`

clicking on the next slide I grab the content of `.categorytext` and have to execute with `.html()` otherwise it's writing in plain text text `"<br>"` text - is there a way to just execute the `<br>` in `categorycontent` that it's not possible to execute other html commands just the `<br>`?!

```
slider.ev.on('rsBeforeAnimStart', function(event) {
    console.log("test");

    var currSlide = $('.rsSlide').eq(slider.currSlideId);
    var content = currSlide.find('.categorytext').text(),
    categorycontent = currSlide.find('.categorytext');
    //var html = currSlide.find('.categorytext').html();

    //This allows all HTML tags to be rendered as HTML  
    if (content.indexOf('<br>') >= 0) {   
        $('.categorytext').html(content);
    }
});
```

Comment: which browser? .indexOf is not supported pre ie8

Comment: What is your issue, didn't get you.

Comment: Hi I just want to execute the <br> command - not other html tags - that users don't have the possibility to add html tags...

Comment: we just supp. IE 8 above, but thx for the hint.

Comment: @andrew It's indexOf for arrays if I recall correctly.

Comment: Just a comment: remember that textarea saves plain text. That means that in your database all breaks will be saved as \r and/or \n, and you will have to replace them with <br/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this :

```
function insertWithBreaks(str, element, empty) {
    var arr = str.split(/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi);
    if (empty) $(element).empty();
    $.each(arr, function(_, a) {
        var node = document.createTextNode(a);
        $(element).append(node).append('<br />');
    });
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GDCtY/1/)

to be called as

```
var str = 'this is a <span>string</span><br>And this is a new line ?';

insertWithBreaks(str, $('#result'), true);
```

I'm assuming HTML is written in the textarea, and that you're not just trying to get the newlines ?

Comment: yes it's written inside a textarea, the tapestry application is converting it into &lt;br&gt; - and then the browser writes <br> in plain text (Royals Slider) - after that I have to .html() that the slider makes the <br> - it's another isue ;) your code works in fiddle - but in Firefox (Firebug) I get str.split is not a function

Comment: There should be no issues with string.split() in Firefox, the split() method is supported everywhere, and I did try the Fiddle in Firefox, and it's working fine for me without errors ?

Comment: thx for the code - the string.split() is another problem I guess, will find it out and post it here, - I accepted the answer because it does what I asked for ;)